# How to migrate a list that has lookup field to another list with a number field

Tags: powershell, migration, content-migration

Is it possible to migrate a list that has a lookup field to another list with a number field
Would I be able to map a lookup field to a number field?

I tried using sharegate but getting error
*Could not convert value (Input string was not in a correct format.).*

Is there a workaround this anyone?

Comment: Its seems dead here..

Comment: All done fixedmy issue